# What is wrong with this update query? I get "no records changed"

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE sb_reviews 
SET clients_id=(SELECT clients_id 
                FROM sb_users 
                WHERE id=sb_reviews.users_id)
```

sb_reviews is a table with a users_id and and a newly created clients_id. I'm trying to grab the clients_id from the sb_users table and put it into the sb_reviews table where sb_users.id=sb_reviews.users_id

This query does not work though, I get no records changed.

Comment: Do you really want to update all rows of the table? I don't see the presence of `WHERE` in your code example. ;p

Comment: Upon further review, I'm not sure I see a problem.  Are you sure there are records to update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your query.

In mysql, if the update has no effect (ie the value in the column isn't changing), it reports as not an update.

If you have already run this, you'll get "no records changed" message every run thereafter (unless data in the second table changes, of course).

Comment: thanks, you were right! I thought it didn't work because i was seeing only 0 values but there were a bunch of records with actual 0 values in the users table.